# How to use startNativeTracing

Tags: android

I am trying to get a trace of an Android device but I am getting

```
ERROR: emulator tracing not enabled
```

How do I get a trace using startNativeTracing() for a real device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about the Trace of the particular function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SDK, You can't use it in real device. For this to work requires running everything inside the qemu emulator; otherwise, this method will have no effect. The trace file is specified on the command line when the emulator is started. For example, the following command line:

```
emulator -trace foo
```

If you want to trace the code in real hardware, `startMethodTracing` method is the one to use. However, it doesn't trace the native code.